# Curly brackets {} to replace 'begin' in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Is it possible to have a macro to use curly brackets {} to indicate a block of statments, so as to replace the 'begin' keyword. Hence, instead of:

```
(if (condition)
    (begin 
        (statement1)
        (statement2)
        (statement3)
        (statement4))
    (else-statement))
```

we may use:

```
(if (condition) {
        (statement1)
        (statement2)
        (statement3)
        (statement4) }
    (else-statement))
```

How can this be accomplished? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is completely possible, and there are several ways to do it. (Quick note before I start, I'm going to use [`block`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/block.html) instead of `begin` because it behaves better with internal definitions.)

#### Method 1: Re-defining `#%app`

One slightly hack-y way is to redefine what function application means so that curly-braces are treated specially. You can do this by defining an `#%app` macro:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/block syntax/parse/define (prefix-in - racket))
;; This #%app macro redefines what function application means so that
;; { def-or-expr ... } expands into (block def-or-expr ...)
;; Otherwise it uses normal function application
(define-syntax-parser #%app
  [{_ def-or-expr:expr ...}
   #:when (equal? #\{ (syntax-property this-syntax 'paren-shape))
   ;; group them in a block
   #'(block def-or-expr ...)]
  [(_ f:expr arg ...)
   #:when (not (equal? #\{ (syntax-property this-syntax 'paren-shape)))
   ;; expand to the old #%app form, from (prefix-in - racket)
   #'(-#%app f arg ...)])
;; using it:
(define (f x)
  (if (< 5 x) {
        (define y (- x 5))
        (f y)
      }
      x))
(f 1) ; 1
(f 5) ; 5
(f 6) ; 1
(f 10) ; 5
(f 11) ; 1
```

#### Method 2: Extending the Reader

Another way would be to define a new `#lang` language and extend the readtable with a different entry for the `{` character. Let me go and do that ...

To define a `#lang` language, you need to put the reader implementation in `your-language/lang/reader.rkt`. Here that's `curly-block/lang/reader.rkt`, where the `curly-block` directory is installed as a single-collection package (`raco pkg install path/to/curly-block`).

**curly-block/lang/reader.rkt**

```
;; s-exp syntax/module-reader is a language for defining new languages.
#lang s-exp syntax/module-reader
racket
#:wrapper1 (lambda (th)
             (parameterize ([current-readtable (make-curly-block-readtable (current-readtable))])
               (th)))

;; This extends the orig-readtable with an entry for `{` that translates
;; { def-or-expr ... } into (block def-or-expr ...)
(define (make-curly-block-readtable orig-readtable)
  (make-readtable orig-readtable
    #\{ 'terminating-macro curly-block-proc))

;; This is the function that the new readtable will use when in encounters a `{`
(define (curly-block-proc char in src ln col pos)
  ;; This reads the list of things ending with the character that closes `char`
  ;; The #f means it uses the racket reader for the first step, so that `{`
  ;; uses the normal behavior, grouping expressions into a reader-level list
  (define lst (read-syntax/recursive src in char #f))
  (cons 'block lst))
```

Using it:

```
#lang curly-block
(require racket/block)
(define (f x)
  (if (< 5 x) {
        (define y (- x 5))
        (f y)
      }
      x))
(f 1) ; 1
(f 5) ; 5
(f 6) ; 1
(f 10) ; 5
(f 11) ; 1
```

Comment: Wow, I wasn't looking for this answer but I'm glad I came across it. Racket sure is flexible.

Comment: @AlexKnauth: is there a way to avoid `(require racket/block)` at the use-site?

Comment: I have experimented with avoiding the need for that `(require racket/block)`, and my attempt is in the [hygienic-reader-extension](https://docs.racket-lang.org/hygienic-reader-extension/index.html) package if you're interested. However, it's pretty limited: you would still need `racket/block` to be at least indirectly required / depended-on. Alexis King proposed a way to make this better by adding a `#%namespaced` form to racket, but that PR was put off because they were planning to do something else better, but that hasn't happened yet... it's complicated

Comment: Alexis King's pull request for `#%namespaced` has some interesting discussion on that avoiding `(require racket/block)` at the use-site question: https://github.com/racket/racket/pull/1458