# Macro of [S:N] for in-range in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I create a macro so that S:N or [S:N] returns a range of numbers starting with S and ending with N (step 1). Basically, it should be able to use it in place of 'in-range'. I tried to create something similar to [Curly brackets {} to replace 'begin' in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369817/curly-brackets-to-replace-begin-in-racket) but could not.

Edit: I tried following as suggested by @soegaard :

my-top.rkt:

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax-rule (my-top S:N)
    (range S N) )

(provide (rename-out [my-top #%top]))
```

test.rkt:

```
#lang racket
 (require "my-top.rkt")

 (1:42)
```

But it does not run. The error is:

```
 #%top: use does not match pattern: (#%top S:N) in: (#%top . 1:42)
```

[1:42] and 1:42 also do not work.

Comment: You do realize that `S:N` is a symbol in scheme, don't you? In general, so is `[S:N]`, unless square brackets are accepted as parentheses.

Comment: Actually, I am not aware of existing significance of S:N and [S:N]. Search for 'colon' on the site is not helpful: https://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=colon nor is one for ':' https://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=%3A. Can you provide me a link.

Comment: You misunderstand. A macro looks like a procedure, i.e. `(do-thing a b c)` might be a macro or a procedure. In this case, `do-thing` is a symbol, i.e. it is atomic. As far as Scheme is concerned, it does not consist of `do` followed by some kind of delimiter, followed by `thing`. The same applies to `S:N`. This is a symbol with no internal structure. You do not want to define a macro, you want to redefine the basic syntax, you want to use a different lexer. That is a reader macro (sounds similar but is very different).

Comment: Although Racket references are very comprehensive, they seem to be too technical and have very few real examples or ready to use code snippets.

Comment: rnso: Read the guide instead of the reference. Read http://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/all.html and http://rmculpepper.github.io/malr/index.html practical information on macros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps to make `S:N` expand to `(range S N)` where `S` and `N` are numbers.

Note that `S:N` is an identifier. Therefore an unbound `S:N` is an unbound identifier. An reference to an unbound identifiers `n` expand to `(#%top . n)`.
Therefore `1:42` expands into `(#%top 1:42)`.

1. Make a macro `my-top` such that `(my-top S:N)` expands to `(range S N)`.
2. Save your macro in file `my-top.rkt` and export it using `(provide (rename-out [my-top #%top]))`.
3. Use your new construct like this:

.

```
 #lang racket
 (require "my-top.rkt")
 1:42
```

Step 1:

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse (for-syntax racket/match syntax/parse))

(begin-for-syntax  
  ; contains-colon? : string -> boolean
  ;   does the string str contain a colon?
  (define (contains-colon? str)
    (regexp-match ".*:.*" str))

  ; split-colon-string-into-numbers : string -> (list number number)
  ;    for a string of the form N:S return a list consisting of the
  ;    numbers corresponsing to the substrings N and S
  (define (split-colon-string-into-numbers str)    
    (match (regexp-match "(.*):(.*)" str)
      [(list _ S-str N-str)
       (list (string->number S-str) (string->number N-str))]
      [_else
       (error 'split-colon-string-into-numbers
              "expected string of the number <number>:<number>")])))

; SYNTAX (my-top . id)
;   (my-top . id)  behaves the same as (#%top . id)
;   except when id has the form N:S in which case
;   (my-top . id) behaves as (range N S)
(define-syntax (my-top stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_my-top . identifier:id)     
     (define str (symbol->string (syntax-e #'identifier)))
     (cond
       [(contains-colon? str)
        (with-syntax ([(S N) (split-colon-string-into-numbers str)])
          (syntax/loc stx
            (range S N)))]
       [else
        #'(#%top . identifier)])]))

;;; Tests

(my-top . 1:5)    ; evaluates to (1 2 3 4)
(define foo 42)
(my-top . foo)    ; evaluates to 42
```

Comment: @rnso You can't use `syntax-rules` to define this macro. You need to use `define-syntax`. See updated answer.

Comment: Perfect. Very insightful.

Comment: But what happens when `S:N` is not undefined?

Comment: The expression `(let ([1:5 42]) 1:5)` evaluates to 42.

The reason is that the Racket expander only introduces `#%top` for unbound identifiers.

Comment: @rnso, @MichaelVehrs, I'm working on a reader version that would still work if `S:N` happened to be defined.

Comment: We look forward to it.

Comment: Ok, I've just add that as another answer.

Answer (score 5):

@soegaard's answer provided a `#%top`-based solution which expands `S:N` when `S` and `N` are literal integers and `S:N` isn't defined as an identifier. However, it's also possible to do this with a reader macro.

I've made two versions: a simple version that only works with literal integers, and another version that works with arbitrary expressions, including variables.

### The literal-integer version

This simple version overrides `[` to begin range expressions like `[S:N]`, where `S` and `N` are literal integers. After the `[`, it reads numeric characters until it finds a `:`, then it reads more numeric characters until it finds a `]`. It converts the strings of numeric characters into integers, and puts those integers into a list representing a call to the `range` function.

It would be used like this:

```
#lang colon-range
;; simple range by itself
[1:42]
;; using a range within a more complicated expression
(for/list ((i [2:42])
           #:when
           (for/and ((j [2:41]) #:when (< j i))
             (not (= 0 (remainder i j)))))
  i)
```

Note that I'm using `((i ....))` instead of the more common `([i ....])` because I can't use `[` and `]` normally any more.

To implement the `#lang colon-range` language, you should put the reader implementation in `colon-range/lang/reader.rkt`, where `colon-range` is installed as a single-collection package.

```
;; s-exp syntax/module-reader is a language for defining new languages.
#lang s-exp syntax/module-reader
racket
#:wrapper1 (lambda (th)
             (parameterize ([current-readtable
                             (make-colon-range-readtable (current-readtable))])
               (th)))

;; This extends the orig-readtable with an entry for `[` to convert
;; `[1:42]` to `(range 1 42)`. In this simplistic implementation, they
;; have to be literal numbers, so it can't refer to a variable.
(define (make-colon-range-readtable orig-readtable)
  (make-readtable orig-readtable
    #\[ 'terminating-macro colon-range-proc))

;; This is the function that the new readtable will use when in encounters a `[`
(define (colon-range-proc char in src ln col pos)
  (define S (read-int-until #\: in src))
  (define N (read-int-until #\] in src))
  (list 'range S N))

;; This reads until it finds the given char (consuming it),
;; and returns an exact integer
(define (read-int-until char in src)
  (define str (list->string (read-numeric-chars-until char in src)))
  (define i (string->number str))
  (unless (exact-integer? i)
    (error 'read "expected an exact integer, given `~a`" str))
  i)

;; This reads until it finds the given char (consuming it), and returns a list
;; of characters. Each char it reads before that needs to be a numeric char,
;; otherwise it throws an error.
(define (read-numeric-chars-until char in src)
  (define c (read-char in))
  (cond [(eof-object? c)
         (error 'read "end-of-file: expected either a number or a `~a`, given `~a`"
                char c)]
        [(char=? char c)
         (list)]
        [(char-numeric? c)
         (cons c (read-numeric-chars-until char in src))]
        [else
         (error 'read "expected either a number or a `~a`, given `~a`"
                char c)]))
```

### The arbitrary-expression version

This version overrides both `[` and `:`. It defines `:` as a separator so that `a:b` reads the same as `a : b`, and it defines `[` as a reader macro that reads a normal list and processes it afterwards. So it will first take `[a : b]` as a list of three elements, and then translate it to `(range a b)`.

It can be used like this:

```
#lang colon-range
;; simple range by itself
[1:42]
;; using a range within a more complicated expression
(for/list ([i [2:42]]
           #:when
           (for/and ([j [2:i]]) ; can refer to a variable
             (not (= 0 (remainder i j)))))
  i)
(define two 2)
(for/list ([i [two:42]] ; can refer to a variable for the start
           #:when
           (for/and ([j [two:(+ 1 (exact-floor (sqrt i)))]]) ; can use arbitrary expressions
             (not (= 0 (remainder i j)))))
  i)
```

The implementation looks like this (again in `colon-range/lang/reader.rkt`). The comments explain some of what it's doing.

```
;; s-exp syntax/module-reader is a language for defining new languages.
#lang s-exp syntax/module-reader
racket
#:wrapper1 (lambda (th)
             (parameterize ([current-readtable
                             (make-colon-range-readtable (current-readtable))])
               (th)))

;; This extends the orig-readtable with entries for `[` and `:` to convert
;; `[S:N]` to `(range S N)`.
(define (make-colon-range-readtable orig-readtable)
  (make-readtable orig-readtable
    #\[ 'terminating-macro colon-range-proc
    #\: 'terminating-macro separator-proc))

;; This is the function that the new readtable will use when in encounters a `[`
(define (colon-range-proc char in src ln col pos)
  ;; This reads the list of things ending with the character that closes `char`
  ;; The #f means it uses the racket reader for the first step, so that `[`
  ;; uses the normal behavior, grouping expressions into a reader-level list
  (define lst (read-syntax/recursive src in char #f))
  ;; This matches on that list to determine whether it has the shape `[S : N]`
  (syntax-case lst (:)
    [[S : N]
     ;; if it is, translate it to `(range S N)`
     (list 'range #'S #'N)]
    [_
     ;; otherwise leave it alone
     lst]))

;; This doesn't read any further and simply returns an identifier containing char,
;; so that it can act like a separator
(define (separator-proc char in src ln col pos)
  (char->identifier char (list src ln col pos 1)))

(define (char->identifier char srcloc)
  (datum->syntax #f (string->symbol (string char)) srcloc))
```