# Macro to write -n as negative of n in Racket

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

If n is defined as 5, (- n) will give a value of -5. Can there be a macro to identify "-n" as negative of n or (- n) in Racket language?

```
> (define n 5)
> n
5
> (- n)
-5
> (-n)
. . -n: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
> -n
. . -n: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If we assume you have no variables in your program with an identifier that begins with a dash you can abuse `#%top`.

The expression `-n` is a variable reference to an unbound variable.
The expander will turn `-n` into `(#%top . -n)`.

If you in module `negative.rkt` write a macro named `my-top` and provide it using
`(provide (rename-out [my-top #%top]))` then you can write `(require "negative.rkt")` to use your own version of `#%top`.

The definition of `my-top` is something like:

if the input identifier x begins with `-` then turn `-something` into `(- something)`
   otherwise return `(#%top . x)`.

See this question for an example of how to redefine `#%top`: [Macro of [S:N] for in-range in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387744/macro-of-sn-for-in-range-in-racket/38398956)

Comment: Wouldn't `#%top` only be used if it's not resolved? Thus `(let ((-x 10)) (+ -x -x))` will work he same with or without the macro?

Comment: @sylwester Yes - that's why I began by assuming that no other identifiers begins with a dash.

Comment: ... but don't actually do any of this. (with great power comes great responsibility)... :)